# Why are Talmidei Chochomim referred to as builders in the Gemara?

Tags: talmidei-chakhamim

We say in davening that Talmidei Chochomim are Marbeh Shalom in the world and it brings a Posuk that essentially says great peace to your children who are students of Hashem and it says do not read children rather read builders. My question is why do we describe Talmidei Chochomim as builders?

Answer (score 2):

[Shabbat 114a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.114a.7?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%90&with=Lexicon&lang2=en):

> מאי ״בנאין״? אמר רבי יוחנן: אלו תלמידי חכמים שעוסקין בבנינו של עולם כל
> ימיהן
>
> Who are builders? Rabbi Yochanan says: Torah scholars, who are busy
> building the world all their lives.

The world was created for the study of Torah. [Pesachim 68b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.68b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אילמלא תורה לא נתקיימו שמים וארץ
>
> If not for Torah [study], the world would cease to exist

[Midrash Tanchuma Bereshit 1](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Bereshit.1.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> הא למדת, שהעולם לא נתיסד אלא על התורה...והקדוש ברוך הוא נתנה לישראל
> שיתעסקו בה ובמצותיה יומם ולילה...שבשביל שומרי התורה העולם עומד
>
> We learn that the world was founded only for the Torah...Hashem gave
> the Torah to Israel to involve themselves in it and its mitzvot day
> and night...it is for those who guard Torah that the world stands.

See also Nefesh Hachaim 4:11.

So the simple meaning of the notion that Torah scholars are builders is that every instant, when the whole world's is renewed from absolute nothing (whether [figuratively or literally](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37960/does-god-continually-recreate-the-physical-world?noredirect=1&lq=1)), it is because they are studying Torah. They build the world. This idea is based off of Rabbi Dovid Brown.

A deeper meaning is that the study of Torah itself builds the world. Or Hachaim  Hokodesh [makes this point](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.114a.7?lang=bi&with=Or%20HaChaim%20on%20Genesis%7CQuoting&lang2=he):

> תלמידי חכמים נקראים בונים כי מה שבפיהם ובלבבם הוא הבונה
>
> Torah scholars are called builders because [the words of Torah that
> are] in their heart and mouths is what builds the world.

This is based on [Bereshit Rabba 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.1.1?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> היה הקדוש ברוך הוא מביט בתורה ובורא את העולם
>
> The Holy One Blessed be He looked into the Torah and created the
> world.

I.e. the Torah is the blueprint of creation, the tool of Hashem's artistry (ibid):

> התורה אומרת אני הייתי כלי אמנותו של הקדוש ברוך הוא
>
> The Torah says I was the tool of the artistry of the Holy One blessed
> be He.

Or Hachaim Hokodesh ties this all together for us by explaining that the builders, the Torah scholars, build the world by the fact

> כי התורה הכינה עולם להתהלך במישרים
>
> ...that the Torah shows the world the straight path they should walk
> on

And this is what the prayer that you have quoted explains as well:

> תַּלְמִידֵי חֲכָמִים מַרְבִּים שָׁלוֹם בָּעוֹלָם, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר
> וְכׇל־בָּנַ֖יִךְ לִמּוּדֵ֣י ה' וְרַ֖ב שְׁל֥וֹם בָּנָֽיִךְ,
> אַל־תִּקְרֵי בָנָיִךְ אֶלָּא בוֹנָיִךְ
>
> Torah scholars *increase peace* in the world, as it is written "And
> all your children shall be taught about Hashem; and great shall be the
> peace of your children" (Isaiah 54:13). Don't read "children" but
> rather "builders".