# Does an object exist if there is no one there to observe it?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, thought

I found this question on Quora and I wonder if Judaism or any Jewish thinkers weigh in on this. In particular, assuming

1. God does everything for a purpose
2. [God is continuously willing that object to exist](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7639/reconciling-nature-with-continuous-creation/11455#11455)
3. The world exists for mankind,

Then- why *would* God continuously will an object to exist if it is not observable? Yet it's hard to imagine that when I leave a room and close the door, it no longer exists.

Comment: @yehuda why is the default non existence. Once something exists, its default is existence. The world created for man has rules that govern consistency and predictability for man. Suspending that would he suspending the system created for man.

Comment: Hashem observes everything that exists.  Thus, it exists.  Should people be so brash to think the universe depends on them?

Comment: the torah describes the existence of many things before man was created

Comment: Here's your answer if there is no nafka mina: for any definition of existence that matters, an object continues existing when unobserved with the proof being we don't find a nafka mina if something is observed or not. If you come up with a nafka mina then we can talk more since we will have to define what notions of existence work for each side. That's philosophy.

Comment: G-d continuously willing the object to exist is not the same as creating it ex nihilo over and over.

Comment: @DoubleAA A simple nafka mina: put the Schrodinger's cat apparatus in a kli cheres.  Wait an hour and remove the kli cheres.  Wait another hour, open the box, and the cat is dead.  Is the kli tamei?

Answer (score -2):

Chazal said that everyone must say, "The world was created for my sake" --  בִּשְׁבִילִי נִבְרָא הָעוֹלָם” [Sanhedrin 4:5] and that we are God's partners in creation --  הַכָּתוּב כְּאִילּוּ נַעֲשָׂה שׁוּתָּף לְהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא בְּמַעֲשֵׂה בְרֵאשִׁית. [Shabbat 10a, 119b]

This parallels what modern physics says: The observer brings the reality around him into being.  So, yes, nothing exists unless humans witness it.  Let me quote the Talmud with my own explanatory additions in brackets:

> Four entered the orchard [and were treated to stiff lectures on quantum mechanics]. Ben Azzai died. Ben Zoma went insane. Acher left Judaism.  Akiva emerged whole. [Ḥagigah 14b].  Rabbi Akiva said: "הַכֹּל צָפוּי, וְהָרְשׁוּת נְתוּנָה -- Everything [that there is to foresee, namely the probabilities of occurrence], is foreseen, and [therefore] free will is given, [because these probabilities are not certainties.]” [Pirkei Avot 3.19]

Comment: The concept of Pardes is to be understood as "quantum mechanics"???

Comment: "the observer brings the reality around him" - where did you see this? from what i read, what counts is if it is observable, not if it is observed